# No visible @interface for RKDynamicMapping declares the selector setObjectMapping: whenValueOfKeyPath: isEqualTo - Restkit 0.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

Hi I'm trying to call setObjectMapping: whenValueOfKeyPath:  isEqualTo on my dynamic mapping object. But it give me this error

**No visible @interface for RKDynamicMapping declares the selector setObjectMapping: whenValueOfKeyPath:  isEqualTo**

```
RKDynamicMapping* dynamicMapping = [RKDynamicMapping new];
[dynamicMapping setObjectMapping:girlMapping whenValueOfKeyPath:@"type" isEqualTo:@"Girl"];
```

Where am I doing wrong ? Is it removed in RestKit 0.2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution . we can use **addMatcher: matcherWithKeyPath: expectedValue: ObjectMapping** property of the RKDynamicMapping object

```
[dynamicMapping addMatcher:[RKObjectMappingMatcher matcherWithKeyPath:@"type" expectedValue:@"Girl" objectMapping:girlMapping]];
```